# Bootstrap template form doest not updating the form details in DJango

Tags: python, django, backend

I am facing this issue. Form save url does'nt working. I tried  but i didnot get any solution this.

Django form doesn't working properly, may be form not saving or URL problem.

Any senior django developer, please guide me.

Thanks.

Codes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ddG.jpg)

Editing ----

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jnaq.jpg)

Edit.html (Template)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="/edit" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Note Title</label>
                  <input type="text" value="{{post.notes_titles}}" name="ntitles" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Description</label>
                  <textarea name="nt" value="{{post.notes}}" cols="20" rows="7" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Note Slug</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nslug" value="{{post.notes_slug}}" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                  </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-4" value="Update">Save</button>
              </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Views.py**
Updated Form

```
def editNote(request, notes_id):

if request.method=='POST':
    ntitles = request.POST.get('notes_titles')
    nt = request.POST.get('notes')
    nslug = request.POST.get('notes_slug')
    post = note(notes_id=notes_id, notes_titles=ntitles, notes=nt, notes_slug=nslug)
    post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/notes')          
else:
    return render(request, 'iapp/edit.html')
```

Comment: there is o path called `edit`

Comment: I didn't get this one? what mean by 0 path? please explain me little more, thanks

Comment: In the template try changing `action="/edit"` to `action="{% url 'editNote' %}"` I'm assuming in your urls.py the 'editNote' Url's **name** is just **editNote**, the URL tag + the **name** in urls.py needs to match. **---Edit:** I'm assuming your Url.py looks like `path('edit', views.editNote, name='editNote')`

Comment: Sweet! So that means the posting URL was wrong.. Might have been `/app1/edit/` (You can inspect the form element if you are interested on what it actually is)
But I recommend using that URL template tag everywhere, that way if you ever decide to change a url (ex: `edit` -> `note/edit`) it'll just automatically do it and you only have to change it in the **url.py**